# Eclipse giving error on a println method

Tags: java, eclipse, println

Typing

```
System.out.println("Hello world");
```

into `eclipse` gives error on the second `"."` and on the `";"`.

The errror message looks like this:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
     MethodHeaderName
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
     QualifiedName
```

This has never happened before. Mind you, this is happening on a computer where I just installed `Eclipse` and the newest `JDK` for `x64` windows 10. Might have something to do with it, but I'm clueless.

Thanks for any response! :)

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. It's very likely that the problem is where the statement exists rather than anything else.

Comment: please post full code.. the statement you have given seems fine.. must be the issue with other  part of your code.

Comment: I think there is a compile error before this line. Show us please the full class

Comment: Sorry, my first time on this page, not used to your ways yet >.<

Comment: also: are those single quotes or double quotes?

Comment: full code:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValutaKalkulator {
 Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);
 
 double NOK = 1.0;
 double EUR = 9.34;
 double USD = 8.46;
 
 System.out.println("");

}

Comment: Don't post the code in comments. Edit the question, and post the code in the question, as properly intented code. There is a button labeled `{}` for formatting the text as code.

Comment: Those are double quotes? The ones I get when I press shift+2, I'm on a norwegian keyboarf

Comment: Your sysout statement needs to live inside a method. It's not a declaration.

Comment: ...Thank you very much, JonK. Silly me. >.<

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Try
  {
    Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);
    double NOK = 1.0;
    double EUR = 9.34; 
    double USD = 8.46; 

 public static void Test(String args[]){
     System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

You can't use System.out.print() like that,you have to run it inside either a constructor or another method.